# CSS3 Clipping divs

Tags: css, css-transforms

Code available at http://jsfiddle.net/rSSXu/

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Child</div>
</div>​

#parent {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:200px;
    width:50%;
    background:#eee;
    overflow:none;

}

#child {
    width:10%;
    height:10%;
    margin:auto;
    background:red;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 300px); 

}
```

I have the following setup, and I would like the parent div to "clip" so that anything outside it is hidden.  A little bit like overflow:none, but that also applies to translates.  Is there a way to achieve this?
Thanks, 
Chris

Comment: Can you give some more information i don't understand the question (EDIT: your fiddle differs from the code in the question so i didn't see the problem Mamadum fixed it)

Comment: you mean you want the parent div to clip things but at the same time you don't want it to clip translated elements. Is it so??

Comment: You can't have self closing div's like <div id="child" /> it HAS to be <div id="child"></div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't remember using overflow: none, try 
    overflow: hidden